# Minimum number of samples in a space of n x m pixels such that each pixel is uniquely sampled.

Tags: combinatorics, optimization

Say we have a space of $n\times m$ pixels. We want to sample each pixel as either $+1$ or $-1$ while all other pixels are valued at $0$. Of note, the location of each pixel is important, and there are dependencies across pixels, so each pixel needs to be **sampled independently**.

To build some intuition, the simplest solution to this problem would be to set all pixels to $0$, then value our first pixel a $-1$, followed by $+1$. We would then move to a second pixel and repeat. This would fully sample the set.

However, we can undoubtedly speed up the process by providing *combinations* of pixels. What is the minimum number of groups of pixels needed to sample the entire space? How might these arrangements of pixels be distributed?

---

Bonus: If we set the requirement that, when a pixel is valued at $(-1,+1)$, all pixels in radius $r$ must be valued at $0$, how many combinations do we encounter, and what is their distribution?

Comment: If you need to sample independently, why is it possible to do other than you suggest, try each pixel separately?  Without your sample independently, a natural thing is to number the pixels from $0$ to $nm-1$ and find the next power of $2$ above $nm-1$  Go through the bits, valuing all the ones that have a $1$ in a given place $+1$, then $-1$, then value the ones with $0$ in that place $+1$ and then $-1$.  That gets you the information in $4 \log_2 (nm)$.  Is this acceptable or not?

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely suitable; I was hoping to beat the multiplicative growth factor by getting clever (and maybe institute some minimum $r$ at which there are no dependencies), but it wouldn't meaningfully decrease the amount of sampling unless $r\approx nm$